# Hyperledger Fabric: How to keep chaincode-calling application and deployed chaincode in sync ? Any ABI equivalent feature?

Tags: interface, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, abi, chaincode

There is no concept of **ABI**(Application Binary Interface) in Hyperledger fabric as it is there in Ethereum/Quorum.

An **ABI** file in Quorum is generated while compiling the Smart-contract(chaincode), which is further used by the client-application as the reference to the function definition of the deployed smart-contract.

**For example:** If there is a function named **getAsset(assetId: *string*)** which returns an **Asset** object, this complete information will be defined in the **ABI** file.

So, In short, **ABI** serves the purpose of an **interface of a deployed smart-contract**, and, also stays with the client-application as a reference of the **function definitions** of the deployed smart-contract, Which omits the possibility of the application being out of sync with the deployed contract and calling the smart-contract's functions with incorrect arguments.

Now, I am wondering how this problem can be solved in **Hyperledger Fabric**.

I was going through **asset-transfer-basic** (javascript application), there I can see a method named **CreateAsset** that accepts ***(assetId, color, owner, size, appraisedValue)*** but they are being passed explicitly.

What I mean by that is, there is no other way to know what arguments **CreateAsset** accepts without manually looking at the implementation of the function in the smart-contract.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: As per my understanding, Without looking at smart-contract you can not find a number of arguments of chain code Or any other functionality as ABI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contract = network.getContract('mychaincode', 'org.hyperledger.fabric');
result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata');
metadata = JSON.parse(result.toString('utf8'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Chaincodes (at least ones implemented using the Contract API) have a `org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata` transaction function that returns a JSON payload describing all the available transaction functions and their parameters.

Using the client SDK you would invoke this by creating a client-side Contract object with the chaincode name and `org.hyperledger.fabric` as the contract identifier. Then invoke the `GetMetaData` transaction using that Contract object. In JavaScript, something like this:

```
contract = network.getContract('mychaincode', 'org.hyperledger.fabric');
result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('GetMetadata');
metadata = JSON.parse(result.toString('utf8'));
```

I'm not sure how well the existence of this transaction function is documented, but the structure of the metadata is documented here:

https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.2/api/tutorial-annotated-contract-metadata.html

Comment: Is this method 'GetMetadata' implemented by default or I should write the implementation of it? Because I'm getting this error. "Error: You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: GetMetadata"

Comment: It should be,     result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata');   in line number 2